# how many columns does line.split() return

Tags: java

I have somewhat unclean data in a CSV.

line.split() will normally return X columns. But sometimes the end of the data is cut meaning it will return X - y columns. This makes the app throw an exception.

Is there a way to know how many columns line.split() has returned or how many columns there are in String[] ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand: what's wrong with the `length` property?

Comment: what do you mean by _" the end of the data is cut"_ ?? you can always check how many column with `line.split().length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the number of splitted strings you have just use :

```
String splittedStrings[] = line.split();
int splitCount = splittedStrings.length;
```

But it depends on your csv data. If it is correct then `splitCount` will be the number of columns you expect, otherwise you might have a delimiter issue and you will get a different number.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `length` property as you want ;) 
if you have index containing `""` then you have to assure the integrity of your datas before by checking all the values and deleting all the `""` values from the table.

For example :

```
    String line = "plop plop";
    String mySplit[] = line.split(" ");
    int nbSplit = mySplit.length;
    System.out.println(nbSplit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that can help:
1) Your column data should not contain the split character otherwise it will produce more columns. 
2) You can limit the number of columns by the limit parameter of the split method.

Answer (score -1):

Use line.split().count and you will have the size of the array.

Comment: Count is ios not Java